# How to make vb.net apps portable?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to make an vb.net application portable?

Comment: Portable between different versions of Windows....

Comment: If you mean portable as in running on non-Windows, look at mono: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29

Comment: Install your VB .NET application on a laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is portable - build your .exe and copy it on your flash drive. Assuming it will be run where there is .net framework, there is no problem!

EDIT: A similar topic here: [Writing USB Drive Portable Applications in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778123/writing-usb-drive-portable-applications-in-c)

Comment: Way to go. Just copy every dll and exe from your Release-Folder, that's it.

Comment: That's "relocatable", not "portable", I would say.

Comment: @skaffman, I've been using http://portableapps.com site for some time, not http://relocatableapps.com ;-)

Answer (score 2):

"portable" has more than one meaning, but if you mean a program that could also run on linux or mac than you need to think [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).  Specifically, look at their [migration analyzer](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "portable".  Certainly, you can build them without external dependencies on things like config files, registry settings, etc.  You'll still need the .NET runtime installed on the target computer, though.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that you can use vb.net to write Silverlight apps; once compiled, this should be fairly portable (onto all Silverlight / Moonlight enabled browsers).

Of course, if you talk about *web* apps, the *client* (html) should already be portable, regardless of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's a desktop application or a web application, the .Net framework needs to be installed on the machine that the app is run on. Generally, the .Net framework is installed with Windows.

It has to be the same version of the .Net framework as the app was developed in (1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5). Which version of the framework is installed depends on the version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought!

Maybe you can make your app executable the normal way (with setup) and then make it into a portable application online using service described at
http://www.abtevrythng.com/2011/12/make-portable-applications-online-for.html#ixzz1flSBi6dZ

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the online portable app "converter" Cameyo to do it. Just install the Cameyo app, launch it, then install the application you made.

Answer (score 0):

You must use VS 2015. Make all your reference dll's to be local copied. Build your solution (with no deploy file extension (publish-> options->deployment))and merge the exe file with your dll with ilmerge ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630 ) (download ILmerge-GUI too) from the Microsoft web site. And have good luck